# .Rows() will not accept a string value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a routine to insert some rows, and to copy over some values.
The amount and position of the rows that need to be inserted are dynamic and stored in variables.

I know I can insert rows by using `Activesheet.rows("2:12").Insert shift:=xlDown`

Now as the 2 and 12 are dynamic I declared variables of datatype `Long` to hold those values. For example:

```
Dim Startvalue as Long
Startvalue = 2
Dim Lengthofinsert as Long
Lengthofinsert = 10
Dim Endvalue as Long
Endvalue = Startvalue + Lengthofinsert
```

Then I wrote the following: `Activesheet.rows("""" & Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue & """").Insert shift:=xlDown` which results in a type mismatch.

Using `debug.print("""" & Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue & """")` the result of this is `"2:12"`, exactly the same as I entered in my first `insert()` statement above.

I thought perhaps first storing the string as a `string` variable might help, but that unfortunately also results in the same type mismatch.

Now I figure rows should take some sort of `Array` or `Range` as argument, but how do I convert my two `Long`'s into that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue).Insert shift:=xlDown
```

You don't need the `""` because `Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue` is already a string (the long values automatically cast into a string due to the concatenation with `&`).

Same like

```
Dim MyRows As String
MyRows = Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue
ActiveSheet.Rows(MyRows).Insert shift:=xlDown
```

---

Or as @Chronocidal pointed out in the comment:
Compare the outputs

```
Debug.print("""" & Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue & """")   'output:   "2:12"
Debug.Print("2:12")                                      'output:   2:12
```

Comment: Using `debug.print("""" & Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue & """")` will give `"2:12"`, but `debug.Print("2:12")` will just give `2:12` - this should illustrate that the inputs are not equivalent

Comment: Well, the two integers actually **become** a string due to the string operation of concatenation  but yes, the result is a string.

Comment: Also just noticed that when I hover over the `string` variable I declared as `Placeholderstring = ("""" & Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue & """")` after the line has been executed, the tooltip shows the value as: `""2:12""`

Answer (score 0):

Have you created `Thisworksheet`? It's not mentioned in your declarations.

Assuming you have,

Try

```
ThisWorkSheet.rows(Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue).Insert shift:=xlDown
```

Otherwise try:

```
Activesheet.rows(Startvalue & ":" & Endvalue).Insert shift:=xlDown
```

Comment: @Jeeped, that only holds for workbooks. I changed my Q to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @CLR I replaced ThisWorkSheet by active sheet in the Q to avoid the confusion, thanks for pointint this out.

Comment: @Jeeped - There is no such property as `ThisWorksheet`. There *IS* a property called `ThisWorkbook` which could be used with `ActiveSheet` like so: `Set Thisworksheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` - hence the question at the start of my answer and therefore the split solution depending on it.